# align 2 matrice for maximum overlap

Tags: algorithm, matrix

So following is an interview problem.

> Given two **N<sup>2</sup>** matrices with entries being `0` or `1`. How can we find out the number of maximum overlapping `1`'s possible?

**Note:** You can only move the matrix upward, downward, leftward and rightward, so rotation is not allowed

Currently I'm stuck at the most naive `O(N^4)` method, which being align the top left corner of one matrix to every possible position of the other matrix and count the all the overlap 1s.

*Example*:

```
   [0 1 0]      [0 0 1]
A: [1 0 0]   B: [0 0 1]
   [1 0 0]      [0 0 0]
```

Then the number of maximum overlapping 1s are **2**, that we alight *(0,2)* of B to *(1,0)* of A, then *(0,2)* and *(1,0)* are both 1, and *(1,2)* and *(2,0)* are both 1.

Can it be optimise from **O(N<sup>4</sup>)**?

Comment: Did your interviewer give you any limits as to the size of the matrix or how the values were generated?

Comment: No he didn't. How does the size of the matrix relate to the algorithm?

Comment: If N=3 as in your example, then the N^4 solution is fine. It's simple, and there's no benefit to coding up something more efficient but complicated. If N can be large, then a more complicated but efficient algorithm is preferable. Often the algorithms with better efficiency for large inputs are not just more complicated, but also slower than their simpler counterparts for small inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If floating-point arithmetics calculations are possible, this problem might be solved with 2D [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation) (using fast Fourier transform intrinsically) in `O(n^2 logn)` time. This method is used in 2D pattern searching.

Not so obvious tip: to implement correlation and get proper results, one should shift values to make "signals" bi-polar (transform zeros to -1 or subtract matrix average from all matrix elements)

Calculate correlation matrix, find index `(dx,dy)` of maximum value - it should correspond to align vector.