# Aligning two binary matrices for maximum overlap

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, binary, counting

I would like to find the number of maximum overlapping `1`'s of two binary matrices, allowing only for translation (rotation and reflection are not allowed). My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263570/align-2-matrice-for-maximum-overlap), but what I want to do is to actually code in an efficient way the "naive" solution proposed by OP in that question.

So, to recap, I have two matrices (**not necessarily of the same size**) with entries being `0` or `1`, for example:

```
   [0 0]      [0 0 1]
A: [1 1]   B: [0 0 1]
   [1 0]      [1 0 0]
```

The maximum overlap can be found by aligning one of the corners of one matrix to every possible position of the other matrix and counting all the overlapping `1`'s. Then, we find than the maximum overlap is **two** and is given when we align the bottom left corner *(2,0)* of A to *(1,2)* of B.

I would like to code in python a simple (and possibly fast) implementation of this method, but I don't really know where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the maximum overlap you can use the `correlate2d` function from scipy:

```
import scipy

scipy.signal.correlate2d(a, b).max()
```

Or you can implement it from scratch using numpy (which is a little bit tricky):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided


def max_overlap(a, b):
    b_p = np.pad(b, ((a.shape[0]-1, a.shape[0]-1), (a.shape[1]-1, a.shape[1]-1)), 'constant', constant_values=0)
    output_shape = (b_p.shape[0] - a.shape[0] + 1, b_p.shape[1] - a.shape[1] + 1)
    b_w = as_strided(b_p, shape=output_shape + a.shape,
                          strides=b_p.strides*2)
    c = (b_w * a).sum(axis=(2,3))
    return c.max()
```